# is referencing or copying a struct of a struct (memset allocated) a valid thing to do?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, sockets, struct

In order to use network information such (udp sockaddr_in and socket number) in a thread (pthread), i setup udp socket in my main function, then i want to create a struct containing ((sockaddr_in) which is a struct and (int socket )) as an argument to the function for pthread_create.

would it be a dangerous thing to copy the struct from a socket created in main into an global function (for the thread) , since it is allocated i suppose outside the stack, or referencing it would be better

here is what im trying to do :

```
rc = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, myfunction, (void *) &StructArg);
```

where the thread1 is where i want to use (void *)myfunction(void* StructArg)

say the (sockaddr_in Addrem) is already population after being  memset

```
struct NetworkInfo { sockaddr_in remote ; int socket ;} ;
NetworkInfo NI;
NI.remote= Addrem;
NI.socket=sock;  // from socket(sock,.....)
```

or is there a better way

I sincerely appreciate the inputs.

many thanks

Comment: `memset` doesn't allocate anything. Perhaps you mean `malloc`?

Comment: actually it's memset, so you see no concern in doing so, would the function copying the socket value of int (of a main established socket), enable it to use the network to send data (inside the function -the function is responsible for packing some particular data) ?

Comment: Read [the documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html). `memset` does not allocate memory. It writes data to an existing location.

Comment: I don't see any problem using `NI.socket=sock;`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where the struct is allocated.  You have to ensure the struct stays in memory until the thread ends.  If the struct is declared as a local variable to the function that calls `pthread_create()`, that is dangerous, eg:

```
void somefunc()
{
    struct NetworkInfo NI;
    // fill NI as needed...
    rc = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &myfunction, &NI);
}
```

Unless you join on the thread in the same function to wait for it to terminate:

```
void somefunc()
{
    struct NetworkInfo NI;
    // fill NI as needed...
    rc = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &myfunction, &NI);
    // ...
    pthread_join(thread1, ...);
}
```

Otherwise, you will have to either declare the struct as a global variable (and don't ever create multiple threads that use it as the same time):

```
struct NetworkInfo NI;

void* myfunction(void *arg)
{
    // use NI as needed...
    return ...;
}

void somefunc()
{
    rc = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &myfunction, NULL);
}
```

Or allocate the struct on the heap and have the thread free it when done using it:

```
void* myfunction(void *arg)
{
    struct NetworkInfo *NI = (struct NetworkInfo*) arg;
    // use NI as needed...
    free(NI);
    return ...;
}

void somefunc()
{
    struct NetworkInfo *NI = malloc(sizeof(struct NetworkInfo));
    // fill NI as needed...
    rc = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &myfunction, NI);
}
```

Alternatively:

```
#include <memory>

void* myfunction(void *arg)
{
    std::auto_ptr<struct NetworkInfo> NI( (struct NetworkInfo*) arg );
    // use NI as needed...
    return ...;
}

void somefunc()
{
    std::auto_ptr<struct NetworkInfo> NI(new struct NetworkInfo);
    // fill NI as needed...
    rc = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &myfunction, NI.get());
    NI.release();
}
```